# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select' SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function

I would like to ask you for help. If I run these queries separately, they are working. When I try to create function I get error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

My function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION INCOME_EXPENSE(@YEAR integer)   
RETURNS table 
AS
    RETURN
        SELECT 
            CONCAT('INCOME ', SUM(AMOUNT)) AS INCOME,  
            (MONTH(date)) AS period
        FROM
            evidence
        WHERE
            YEAR(date) = @year AND amount > 0 
        GROUP BY 
            MONTH(date) 

    SELECT  
        CONCAT('Year income ', SUM(amount)) AS income, 
        YEAR(date) AS period
    FROM
        evidence
    WHERE
        YEAR(date) = @year AND amount > 0
    GROUP BY
        (YEAR(date))

    SELECT
        CONCAT('Expenses ', SUM(amount)) AS Expenses, 
        MONTH(date) as period
    FROM
        evidence
    WHERE
        YEAR(date) = @year AND amount > 0
    GROUP BY
        MONTH(date)

    SELECT
        concat('Year expenses ', SUM(amount)) AS expenses, 
        YEAR(date) AS period 
    FROM
        evidence
    WHERE
        YEAR(date) = @year AND amount > 0
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(date)
```

Comment: You should be able to do this in a single SELECT anyway with GROUPING SETS

Comment: @nwind - Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you and they both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful answer. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Place a [`UNION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql) or [`UNION ALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql) between each of your queries.

---

`UNION` Specifies that multiple result sets are to be combined and returned as a single result set.

`UNION ALL` Incorporates all rows into the results. This includes duplicates.

```
SELECT CONCAT ('INCOME ', Sum(AMOUNT)) AS INCOME, (month(DATE)) AS period
FROM evidence
WHERE year(DATE) = @year AND amount > 0
GROUP BY month(DATE)

UNION ALL

SELECT CONCAT ('Year income ', Sum(amount)) AS income, year(DATE) AS period
FROM evidence
WHERE year(DATE) = @year AND amount > 0
GROUP BY (year(DATE))

UNION ALL

SELECT CONCAT ('Expenses ', Sum(amount)) AS Expenses, month(DATE) AS period
FROM evidence
WHERE year(DATE) = @year AND amount < 0
GROUP BY month(DATE)

UNION ALL

SELECT CONCAT ('Year expenses ', Sum(amount)) AS expenses, year(DATE) AS period
FROM evidence
WHERE year(DATE) = @year AND amount < 0
GROUP BY year(DATE)
```

Check out an example: [UNION Example](http://rextester.com/VUSH75839)

You'll see that the query which uses `UNION ALL` includes all rows, even duplicates, whereas the query combination that uses `UNION` returns only unique rows.

Comment: @nwind Do you need any additional help with this or has your question been answered?